# how could this work with eclipse, but not in an actual phone?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location, criteria

```
 LocationManager locationManager;
    String context = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(context);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Just after that i take the latitude and the longitude to put in on a server, but it crash my phone.

Comment: Stack trace? Have you tried monitoring your LogCat output using DDMS (part of the Eclipse ADT plugin) to find out why it crashes your phone? This is absolutely necessary for development.

Comment: Check the Settings- Location on you phone and see if there is selected  any option to determine location.

Comment: There was nothing on the Logcat because it worked fine with Eclipse, but you were right, i tought i turned on my GPS option, but i didn't, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Settings>Location and Security>My
>   Location

service is not enabled into your Android device

hence your`locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` ( If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.)  is producing null value, Later then you are invoking `double latitude = location.getLatitude(); double longitude = location.getLongitude();` with a null value object, so your application is crashing.